# JavaScript Cookies i'm getting NaN property

Tags: javascript, cookies

I tried to save a number in javascript in document.cookie.
But when i try to get a cookie with a number i'm always getting NaN when i try to display it

```
var playerCoffeeCount = 0;
function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) { //Setting a cookie (just a shortcut for making cookies)
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name) { //Getting a cookie (another shortcut)
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x == c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}

function saveGame(){
    setCookie("playerCoffeeCookie", playerCoffeeCount, 999);
}
function loadGame(){
    playerCoffeeCount = getCookie("playerCoffeeCookie");
}
function displayCookie(){
    document.getElementById("coffeecount").innerHTML= "Coffee: " + Math.floor(playerCoffeeCount);
}
```

This cookie system in JavaScript saves the value, but it displays as a NaN... Please help :(

Comment: That's because the value is a string, not a number.

Comment: Please show the code that calls this and the code that displays the cookie.

Comment: @Diodeus Strings containing numbers are usually converted automatically when used in arithmetic expressions.

Comment: it works fine for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ja5pw/

Comment: Added the variable and display function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, working good.

```
 function createCookie(name,days,value) {
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
            var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
        }
        else var expires = "";
        document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
    }

    function readCookie(name) { //cookie reader function
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return       c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
        }
        return null;
    }

    function eraseCookie(name) { //cookie eraser function
        createCookie(name,"",-1);
    }

    createCookie("test", 1, 1);
    var mycookie= readCookie("test");
    mycookie = parseFloat(mycookie);
    console.log(mycookie);
```

[image: console log]

Comment: You need set a number here->
  setCookie("playerCoffeeCookie", 365, 999);

Answer (score 0):

I just found out you just have to disable autosave then hard reset then immediately exit out the tab and if it doesn't work keep trying till it does

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).